# ConcurrentExecution Exception & nio.file.NoSuchFileException when creating Symbolic Link

Tags: java, multithreading, nio

I have a directory with JSON files which needs to be iterated to get the name of document `dName`. Multiple JSON files can have same `dName`. Then a symbolic link needs to be created to that JSON file from a folder named `output/dName/match`. The threads first check if the `dName` folder exists first if not it creates them first. I have the following code that creates symbolic links.

```
protected static void copyFile(String docName, Path tFilePath) throws IOException {
    final String docFolderName = "output" + docName.substring(0, docName.lastIndexOf("."));
    final String opDir = docFolderName + "match";
    path = Paths.get(opDir);
    if (Files.notExists(path)) {
        Files.createDirectories(path);
        outputAnnotationDirs.add(path.toString());
    }
    try {
        Files.createSymbolicLink(Paths.get(opDir).resolve(tFilePath.getFileName()), tFilePath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}


protected static void Mapper(String Dir,int numThreads) throws Exception {
    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
    final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Future<?>> futures = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Future<?>>();
    final JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    try {
        Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(Dir), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(final Path tFile, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                futures.add((Future<String>) executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        JsonObject jsonObject = null;
                        FileReader reader = null;
                        try {
                            reader = new FileReader(tFile.toFile());
                            jsonObject = (JsonObject) parser.parse(reader);
                            JsonArray instancesArray = (JsonArray) jsonObject.get("instances");
                            String dName = instancesArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("dname").toString();
                            copyFile(dName, tFile);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        } finally {
                            try {
                                if (reader != null)
                                    reader.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {

                                logger.error(e);
                            }
                        }                           
                    }
                }));
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        Future<?> future;
        while ((future = futures.poll()) != null) {
            try {
                future.get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                for (Future<?> f : futures)
                    f.cancel(true);
                if (executorService != null)
                    executorService.shutdown();
                throw new Exception(e);
            }
        }
        if (executorService != null)
            executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

However an exception keeps occurring at the line where symbolic link is created.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:`

Ex: Exception at `output/document1/match/ok.json`

If I'm right the symbolic links are created only after that line gets executed. Then why does the error occur? And individual symbolic Link creation by a thread why does it cause `concurrent.ExecutionException`?

Comment: path = Paths.get(opDir); is probybly a race condition. Can you try to use a local variable? Can you paste the complete Stacktrace?

Comment: That was the issue..Please post the same as answer so that I can award you answer the bounty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment:

```
 path = Paths.get(opDir);
```

is a race condition.

Answer (score 2):

> Then why does the error occur?

The error occurs because your `"parent directory creation"` is not creating all parent directories before creating the symlink. For eg: If you have json entry of `"dname": "a/b/c/somedname1.txt"` - folders `a/b/c` don't seem to be created. That's why `NoSuchFileException` is thrown. Now, you already do have a logic to create directories, but why did that not work? That would have worked fine, had you run it in a single thread. Why not in multiple threads?

Because, the `path` variable is shared across all threads and is simultaneously getting modified by many threads.

```
path = Paths.get(opDir);
if (Files.notExists(path)) {
    Files.createDirectories(path);
    outputAnnotationDirs.add(path.toString());
}
```

When run in multiple threads, say, one thread has `dname:a/b/c/dname1.txt` and a second thread has `dname:e/f/g/dname2.txt`. The first thread may end up creating e/f/g instead of a/b/c directories. The classic concurrency problem. Making that `path` a local variable will solve your issue immediately. Or run your process in a single thread.

1. Had your original file gotten removed by another process, you would have gotten a `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.
2. Had your symlinks were already present, you would have gotten a `java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException`.
3. `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException` happens when you cannot act on the file, like DELETE. Or when you try to create a file/symlink when parent folders aren't there.

> And individual Symbolic Link creation by a thread why does it cause
>   concurrent.ExecutionException?

The `NoSuchFileException` is wrapped by your `RunTimeException` is wrapped by `ExecutionException` when you do a `get` on the `future`. Because, the RunTimeException happened on a different thread and your below call happens on the main thread. So Executor wraps the Exception and fires at the below call which is invoked from the main thread.

```
future.get();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.. There is a race condition. Change the scope of the relative path variable to a local variable.

Answer (score -3):

To me it looks like NoSuchFileException tells you what is the problem. To create symbolic link to a file, the file should exist.

Comment: The json file to which a symbolic link is created does exist!! It says the symbolic link file doesn't exist which is weird as that statement is supposed to create it..

Comment: This is wrong. The target of a symbolic link is not required to exist.